# How to improve model's predictive accuracy brms / rstan

Tags: r, bayesian, beta-regression, brms

**General question**: How can you improve a model after seeing that it poorly predicts your data (i.e. posterior predictive distribution doesn't recover your data well)?

I am fitting a multilevel beta regression model with `brms` using continuous proportion data as an outcome that have been "squeezed" to fit the open (0,1) interval. 6% of the un-transformed data were zeros, and 0.6% were ones. I used the following function per Smithson & Verkuilen, 2006 (citation below) to fit the `y` data to the open interval:

```
p_star <- function(y, n) {
    output <- (y*(n - 1) + 0.5)/n 
    return(output)
}
```

Predictor variable `x` is a continuous variable ranging from about 0-14 and there are 114 `id_var` groups. Number of observations is over 5,700. Here is my model structure:

```
beta_fit <- brm(formula = y ~ x + (1 | id_var), 
       data = data,
       family ="beta",
       prior = c(prior(student_t(3, 0, 2.5), class = "Intercept"), # default
                 prior(normal(0, 1), class = "b"), # somewhat informed
                 prior(gamma(0.01, 0.01, class = "phi"), # default
                 prior(student_t(3, 0, 2.5, class = "sd")), # default
       chains = 4, 
       iter = 2000, 
       warmup = 1000,
       cores = 2,  
       seed = 1234)
```

The model converges, but when looking at the posterior predictive distribution,  it seems like the model predictions don't follow the actual data very well.

[image]

I have tried making the beta priors and the intercept priors less vague, running a group-level slopes and group-level intercepts model, changing the `sd` priors to `exponential(1)` and logging the `x` variable. None of these seemed to change the posterior predictive distribution much.

Any suggestions to getting a better fit? Could my data just be too noisy? Here is a plot with 100 draws from the expectation of the posterior predictive distribution overlain on a scatterplot of the data.

[image]

**Citation**: Smithson, M., & Verkuilen, J. (2006). A better lemon squeezer? Maximum-likelihood regression with beta-distributed dependent variables. Psychological methods, 11(1), 54.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what I'm looking at with that plot, but intuitively this more likely has to do with the linearity part of your model rather than any priors.

Comment: the "y" line is a kernel density of my outcome variable (the raw data) and "y_rep" is a density of simulated values from the posterior predictive distribution. I got it from running my model through the "pp_check" command of the "bayesplot" package.

Comment: What was the original scale for your response variable, $y$? You mentioned it's "squeezed" to $(0,1)$. Also, any way you can share more info on the raw data or share a sample or simulated example of the data?

Comment: I edited the original post to clarify. Short answer: the untransformed y data are proportions on the [0,1] interval. I am working on simulating some data. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on $y$. Seeing the scatter plot looks like it could be hinting at the $x$ variable being an _ordinal_ variable. Is that the case? If so, then [Estimating Monotonic Effects with brms](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/articles/brms_monotonic.html) may be useful here.

Comment: The x variable is in fact a continuous variable (a metric on the percentage scale). Each observation of y is taken at a given day, while the x variable looks ordinal because all observations in a given month will have the same x variable (e.g., all observations in February will have the x value of 4.3, but unique y values; all observations in March will have an x value of 6.6, but unique y values). On reflection, maybe this is something to account for in the model...

Comment: @Will what does it look like if you add an x^2 term to your mean?

Comment: @JohnMadden thanks for the suggestion. I gave this a try, and it seems to turn up essentially the same predictions, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**
Modeling the `phi` term as a function of `x` and `id` seemed to be key. I also ended up running it with a smooth term on `x` and as a zero-one-inflated beta on the untransformed `y`, which helped to pick up the behavior at the tail ends of the distribution of `y`.